# Git pull no such remote ref error

Tags: git, git-branch, git-pull

I have a local branch on my Windows 8.1 computer that some how lost its tracking to the remote origin, and could no longer pull or push. Patched it up with

```
$ git branch -u origin/LostBranch
Branch LostBranch set up to track remote branch LostBranch from origin.
```

But after that, attempting to pull yield the following errors

```
git.exe pull -v --progress         "origin"

error: no such remote ref 76b9285a434564e6de16336307092c7ad6cb8015 refs/heads/feature/meetingroom
error: no such remote ref 97fe8cf5a85a4d1b2ac9f879507e75cfc2680c65 refs/heads/master
error: no such remote ref aada820ffee201d3976d3a7c7358a04f1c99860c refs/heads/LostBranch

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)
```

Am confused what this really means and how to fix this?

Comment: Does `git fetch` work?

Comment: A reinstallation of msysgit and reboot worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled msysgit, restarted the operating system, and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

It might mean the branch has been "force pushed", changing its history.
That means the remote tracking branch (the pointer in your local repo to the last fetch SHA1 from `origin` doesn't exist anymore.

It can also happen when the other branches have been removed (a git fetch --prune can help cleaning the local remote tracking branch)

Or it can happen if somehow the remote origin doesn't refer to the right repo.

In any case, it is best to fist try to clone that repo elsewhere and see what is going on in that new clone, instead of messing too much the current local repo.